# Magento2: Custom block data not showing on frontend side

Tags: magento2, custom-block

I have created a simple module. But block data not display front end.

please find the below code

**Block**

```
<?php
namespace Codism\Csr\Block\Index;
class Additional_Csr extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function showCustomView()
    {
        return __('Hello Magento 2');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Codism\Csr\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Codism\Csr\Block\Index\Additional_Csr" name="custom_view" template="Codism_Csr::additional_csr.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**View**

```
<span style="font-weight: 400;"><?php echo $block->showCustomView(); ?> </span>
```

**Route**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="csr" frontName="csr">
            <module name="Codism_Csr" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you please upload your routes.xml file and layout xml file name ?

Comment: Please check route file @RohanHapani

Comment: please check layout file name : csr_index_index.xml

Comment: Ok, I will  check and update you.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change block file name :

**It should be like this : /app/code/Codism/Csr/Block/Index/AdditionalCsr.php**

```
<?php
namespace Codism\Csr\Block\Index;
class AdditionalCsr extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function showCustomView() {
        return __('Hello Magento 2');
    }
}
```

**Replace this below code in layout file : /app/code/Codism/Csr/view/frontend/layout/csr_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Codism\Csr\Block\Index\AdditionalCsr" name="custom_view" template="Codism_Csr::additional_csr.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Clean cache and check output.

Comment: Can you explain what was the issue in my file? @RohanHapani

Comment: Your file name was incorrect.

Comment: Ok, xml file name also incorrect?

Comment: Prv xml file name was **additional_csr.xml**.

Comment: Yes. It should be csr_index_index.xml. I mention all file path in answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create multiple blocks?